# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string 01830

Tags: sql, oracle

**My query:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM pd_heat_data
WHERE treatend_act LIKE TO_CHAR(current_date + 1,'YYYY-MM-DD%') AND (
     ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(treatend_act,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
> '00:00:00' ) 
AND ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(treatend_act,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
< '06:00:00' )
);
```

**Table structure:**

```
HeatID         TREATEND_ACT(varchar2)
0001027184     2018-11-23 02:20:25,906
0001027399     2018-11-23 04:45:02,571
```

**System Date and Time settings:**

```
Short Date: yyyy-MM-dd
Long Date:  dd MMMMM,yyyy
Short Time: hh:mm tt
Long Time:  hh:mm:ss tt
No AM andPM
```

Comment: While it may be apparent from your query for some what you are trying to do, it is helpful to everybody reading your question if you explain a bit about what you were actually trying to achieve. Also, please don't  store date/timestamp as `VARCHAR2`, it's not a good design practice.

Comment: @deependra679: As you are using strings (varchar2) and your conversions (`TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR`) specify formats, your date/time settings do not play a big role. (Otherwise, remember, that it's more about your session settings, not your server settings.) If you intend to sticking to date/time as text and double conversion, you can try to use `TO_TIMESTAMP(treatend_act, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,FF3')`.

Answer (score 1):

Because your query is trying to convert whole string to date format of which cannot be recognized by to_date function as a whole, you may try to apply `substr` first as :

```
with pd_heat_data( treatend_act ) as
( select '2018-11-23 02:20:25,906' from dual )
select TO_CHAR(
          TO_DATE(substr(treatend_act,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
       ,'HH24:MI:SS') as "Derived Time"
  from pd_heat_data;

Derived Time
------------
  02:20:25
```

and for the exact query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM pd_heat_data
 WHERE treatend_act LIKE TO_CHAR(current_date + 1,'YYYY-MM-DD%') AND (
     ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(treatend_act,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
> '00:00:00' ) 
AND ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(substr(treatend_act,1,19),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'HH24:MI:SS') 
< '06:00:00' )
);
```

or there's no need for extra conversion, substr might be applied directly as @Hilarion(thanks to him) pointed out :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM pd_heat_data
 WHERE treatend_act LIKE TO_CHAR(current_date + 1,'YYYY-MM-DD%') 
   AND substr(treatend_act,1,19) > '2018-11-23 00:00:00'  
   AND substr(treatend_act,1,19) < '2018-11-23 06:00:00';
```

*and as much as possible try to move your data at `treatend_act` to a column of type `date`.*

Comment: When already doing substrings, then why use `TO_CHAR` and `TO_DATE`? Woudn't it be easier/faster to do `SUBSTR(treatend_act, 12, 8) > '00:00:00'`? And I fully agree, that @deependra679 should rather fix the table definition and use `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` column type for `treatend_act`.

Comment: When I saw your simplified query, I actually think there can be something more efficient (i.e. be able to use an index range scan on `treatend_act` also to cover hours). Something like `treatend_act > TO_CHAR(current_date + 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD "00:00:00,000"') AND treatend_act < TO_CHAR(current_date + 1, 'YYYY-MM-DD "06:00:00,000"')`. What do you think?

Comment: The above would replace the whole `WHERE` condition (covering both the date, done previously by `LIKE` and time, covered by substrings).

Comment: @Hilarion sure, creating an index is nice during range scan mostly, but before index we need to move the data to a date type column.

Comment: I agree on date columns in this case, but range scans are also possible with text columns. As here we have a very specific text formats, this kind of scan should still be possible.

Comment: @Hilarion yes, better to include dates also by using `substr(treatend_act,1,19) > '2018-11-23 00:00:00' and substr(treatend_act,1,19) < '2018-11-23 06:00:00'` or whatever the date range is.

Comment: You can even loose the `LIKE`. Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e63b02/9/0 (and the execution plan shows, that a proper range scan does work).